# Using different Secrets in sts replicas

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-secrets

I'm trying to use different secrets on a StatefulSet, based on the index o the pods.
Here is the things I tried:

```
      env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name

        - name: SECRET_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: key
              name: mysecret-$(POD_NAME)

        - name: SECRET_HOST
          value: myhost-$(POD_NAME)
```

However, `mysecret-$(POD_NAME)` is not correctly sobstituted as parameter, while `myhost-$(POD_NAME)` acts correcly.

How can I solve this problem? The goal is to set different variables from secret/configmaps on different replicas of the StatefulSet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this is not supported. The only volumes you can have differ are the PVs. Instead you would use a single secret with keys or whatnot based on the pod index, and write your software to read from the correct key.